# How to add Autoroute for taxonomy in orchard cms?

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I want to add a path like (product->adidas->shoes->shoe1) in autoroute in blogpost in Orchard CMS.How can I create this path?
I use this path

```
{Content.Fields.BlogPost.Category.TermPathSlug}/{Content.Slug}
```

it shows only products/adidas and not show the full path.How can Generate the full path?

Comment: what does it show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{Content.Fields.BlogPost.Category.TermPathSlug}/{Content.Slug}
```

I use this path and now it's correct.But it shows product->adidas->shoes->shoe1.
Don't show the title of article.How can I show the title?

```
product->adidas->shoes->shoe1->The shoe name
```

Comment: You should create a new question: asking a question in an answer is unlikely to work.